# Manipulation with multiples fetch and then

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch-api

I'm learning promises for the school and there a lot of things that I don't understand.

```js
async function getCompanion(name){
const response = await fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=" + name)
if(response.status !== 200) throw `HTTP error: ${response.status}`;
const data =  response.json()
return data
.then((body) => {
  const [index] = body.results;
  const ceo = index.episode 
  let friends = [];
  friends.push(ceo);
  return fetchAll(friends);
   
    
})
.then((body2) => {
  const [index2] = body2;
  const ceo2 = index2.characters
  let friends2 = [];
  friends2.push(ceo2);
  //console.log(friends2)
  return fetchAll(friends2)
}).then((body3) =>{
  console.log(body3);
  
})

.catch( (error) => {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`)
})
}



async function fetchAll(urls){
  const res = await Promise.all(urls.map(u => fetch(u)))
  const jsons = await Promise.all(res.map(r => r.json()))
  console.log(jsons)
  return jsons
  
}
```

What I want to do:

Its a async function that when you pass a name you get the name of the companions that share a episode with the name used, my problem is that the first .then works like I want, I get the episodes where the character take part, but the second `fetchAll` don't work, and I don't know why, the idea is that the second `fetchAll` get the data of each character in `friends2`.

I think my code is a mess, but I'm starting to learn promises, sorry if the code is horrible.

Comment: `await` and `.then()` are alternative syntaxes. Within any given funtion, don't mix them.

Answer (score 0):

```
.then((body) => {
  const [index] = body.results;
  const ceo = index.episode 
  let friends = [];
  friends.push(ceo);
  return fetchAll(friends);
    
})
```

Do this change and it should work. ***fetchAll()*** is a asynchronous function which returns promise, either you need to put await before it or just directly return it because anyway you are not using that ***characters*** constant.

Comment: hello, i changed, seemse more clean with this change but im getting the same problem the later fetchAll(friends2) is getting this result: [ { error: 'There is nothing here.' } ] and don't know why, when i log friends2 i have the array of urls, in theory fetchall need to work.

Comment: Hi, I tried to hit the API you used, the value `episode` which is already and array. So, your the value of `friends` or `friends2` will be `[  ["link1", "link2"] ]` like that, don't push episodes into another array. just pass `episode ` directly to the `fetchAll()` function.